# Files in Cygwin are always executable

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin

I installed Cygwin on my Windows 10 machine, but I found that all the files in Cygwin are executable, whatever the file extensions are.

How should I set the file permissions correctly.

Comment: MS-Windows file systems do not support permissions inside the file system as unixoid systems do.

Comment: I'd respectfully disagree with arkascha, but as I don't have Cygwin installed, I can't test in that environment. yufw, go to your cygwin command line,  and do `echo "abc" > myFile.txt ; ls -l myFile.txt; chmod 644 myFile.txt ; ls -l myFile.txt` and edit your question to include those results. (use the `{}` tool on highlighted text to correctly format for display). If it doesn't work, then there is no sense messing with `find`.

Comment: I would assume that Cygwin is faithfully telling you that the Windows permissions on the file permit execution, which is entirely normal on Windows.  Does this actually represent a problem, or are you just trying to make it "look the same" as a real UNIX system?  (You might want to consider running Linux in a VM rather than Cygwin.)

Comment: This actually is a problem for me, for instance, I have several cross-platform Git repositories in Cygwin and Linux, and the file permissions are not correct, so I have to manually set the permissions whenever I make a commit in Cygwin.